# Попытки настроить Python 3.10.2 Linux mint

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, linux-mint

Прохожу курс и в дз было поставить python 3.10.2 в PyCharm как основной ,но когда пытаюсь добавить итропритатор мне выдает ошибку

> Failed to create virtual environment

Качал я его около 3 раз разными способами и думаю ,что может быть ошибка в этом,но нехватает понимания в чем именно я обосрался
Вот что выдает при запросе :

```
 whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.10  
/usr/bin/python3.8  
/usr/lib/python3.10  
/usr/lib/python2.7  
/usr/lib/python3.9  
/usr/lib/python3.8 /etc/python3.10 /etc/python3.8  
/usr/local/lib/python3.10  
/usr/local/lib/python3.8  
/usr/include/python3.8
```

Comment: Решил проблему !!! У меня не был установлен venv под python 3.10 и поскольку я устанавливал этот venv под линукс в целом ,то думал ,что этого будет достаточно

Comment: "итропритатор" ❤️

Answer (score 1):

1)В Pycharm и в правом верхнем углу перейдите в "Edit Configurations".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2)Там у вас будет "Python interpreted", выберите здесь нужную версию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое,но вопроса заключался в другом просто за ночь мне потраправили мой вопрос модеры

Comment: @davidmydak так не должно быть. Может попробуете исправить вопрос, чтобы донести свою задачу